# Does somebody know what charset the HTTP Headers used to encode?

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, http-headers

Like the problem described by title, my problem is when I read the  Http header that  returned  from the server in the android programs , it appears Disorderly code of strings, so, what I  don't know is, what kind of charset the server used to encoding the http response Headers ?and what charset the andorid used to decode the http response headers?
How do I escape or deal the Garbled?

Comment: You're going to get better answers if you actually put what the "garbled" text is here in the question, along with how you got it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What encoding to use when interpreting HTTP/1.1 header field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841394/what-encoding-to-use-when-interpreting-http-1-1-header-field-value)

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTP Headers are MIME, see [RFC 822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/) where it is defined as ASCII.

> 3.1.2. STRUCTURE OF HEADER FIELDS
>
> Once a field has been unfolded, it may be viewed as being composed of
>   a field-name followed by a colon (":"), followed by a field-body, and
>   terminated by a carriage-return/line-feed. The field-name must be
>   composed of printable ASCII characters (i.e., characters that have
>   values between 33. and 126., decimal, except colon). The field-body
>   may be composed of any ASCII characters, except CR or LF. (While CR
>   and/or LF may be present in the actual text, they are removed by the
>   action of unfolding the field.)

Then [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)

> describes extensions to RFC 822 to allow non-US-ASCII text data in
>   Internet mail header fields