# How to read HTTP response headers with specified charset encoding when using HttpClient

Tags: java, character-encoding, http-headers, httpclient

There is a Chinese word in the response header. I must read the headers with the UTF-8 character encoding. But I don't know how to set this encoding in `httpclient`. How do I tell it which character encoding to use for headers?

Comment: Are you using Apache HttpClient?

Comment: Corrected English. Slightly clarified. Added specific tags.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416470/does-somebody-know-what-charset-the-http-headers-used-to-encode

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841394/what-encoding-to-use-when-interpreting-http-1-1-header-field-value

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Apache HttpClient`, it must be taken care when you convert the response to `String` using `getResponseBodyAsString`

> If the response is known to be a String, you can use the
>   getResponseBodyAsString method which will automatically use the
>   encoding specified in the Content-Type header or ISO-8859-1 if no
>   charset is specified.

See more details [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/charencodings.html).

Answer (score 0):

RFC 7230, the standard for HTTP, [notes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#page-25):

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset, supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset.
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data.

So, how do you **know** the header field is encoded with UTF-8? I'm guesssing that the server has not encoded the header value using RFC2047. In that case, your client program should not be trying to interpret the header value as UTF-8 text, but should instead treat it as opaque data.